# Git. Fix on production

Tags: git

What is recommended workflow if there is bug happened on production, on origin/master branch. Assuming that developers work on origin/dev branch and it's already went ahead of master?

I have some ideas. Would be nice to get recommendations, best practices. Like use 'tags'..

Asumming that all happens in enterprise environment. The company that used to use central repo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are asking about git workflow. I suggest to stick with gitflow:

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

As for your initial question: According to gitflow production means master branch in gitflow. To fix bug in pruduction you need create hotfix branch from your "production" commit, fix bug, and merge it to master and develop.

Note for gitflow there exits higher level wrapper on git for this and similar operations: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow

Comment: Nice links. Like in Alice in wonderland: 'with pictures and conversations'

Answer (score 3):

Create a "Hotfix" Branch from master. Fix your Problem and merge them back in both branches. Don't create them from dev then you have all the changes to that point in your new branch.

https://de.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Answer (score 1):

@ses: With your description and my understanding your first version has been shipped to master that is production environment.

If you want to fix a bug on production create "Hotfix" branch off master.
Resolve the bug in that and then merge it in master.

Once resolved then the "master" branch can then be merged to "origin/develop" as the code resides in master is **error free**